# linux kernel process book keeping

Tags: linux-kernel, scheduler

I am trying to implement some book-keeping in linux kernel. I want to do start some logging just before a process starts executing on CPU. Again I have to update my statistics once the process yields the CPU.

I was wondering what exactly is the place I should add my code.

Is it schedule() or switch_to() ??

I understand that interrupts are disabled before executing switch_to()..

Are interrupts disabled before a call to schedule() ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interrupts are not disabled before a call to `schedule()`. The interrupts disabled directly in `__schedule()` when it obtains `rq->lock`.

The `context_switch()` is architecture-dependent, so you should add your code in `__schedule()` if your code is architecture-independent and you don't want to write your code for every arch.